# Can I change the Keep-Alive timeout for a S3 origin with Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, keep-alive

Is it possible to increase the Keep-Alive Timeout for a CloudFront distribution when you're not using a custom origin?  I'm using S3 as the origin.

All the docs and threads I can find focus on custom origins, and indeed the CloudFront [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginKeepaliveTimeout) and dashboard specify that the Keep-Alive Timeout can only be changed if using a custom origin.

The default is 5 seconds and it seems unusually low, given the values used by other providers (read more [here](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/276)).

Even on the page for requesting limit upgrades, Keep-Alive Timeout is not one of the available options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to increase the Keep-Alive Timeout for a CloudFront distribution when you're not using a custom origin?

No, and why should it?

CloudFront -> S3 is within Amazon's **own** infrastructure and they will handle keeping requests alive if needs be on **their** side.

Why do **you** want to increase the Keep-alive timeout between **their** services (CloudFront and S3)?

---

For requesting a service limit increase for the Keep-alive timeout for custom origins, it's the `Request Timeout per Origin` limit that you've highlighted in your image. It's just worded differently.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to fix is that the browser client often has to re-establish connections with my server even for requests that are sent within a short time frame. So I thought the keep-alive header was the way to do minimize that. It seems you're suggesting that the value in the aws dashboard only affects CloudFront -> S3, rather than CloudFront -> browser client. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct, that value only essentially would affect CloudFront -> S3 which is why it's set to external origins only

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying. Then do you know how to set the keep-alive timeout between the browser client and cloudfront?